# Least Squares Line Fitting

Tags: linear-algebra

So yeah, I want to find a general line equation $Ax + By + C = 0$ that best fits a set of $n$ points.

We know upfront that the geometric center $(x_g, y_g)$ is a point that lies on this line, hence we can write the line equation as: $A(x - x_g) + B(y - y_g) = 0$. Now all we need to do is to find the normal $(A, B)$ of this line.

The cost function to optimize (sum of squares of distances from those $n$ points to the line) is: $F(A, B) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (A(x_i-x_g) + B(y_i-y_g))^2$.

I then compute derivatives of this function with respect to $A$ and $B$. After equating those derivatives to $0$ I get:

$A = \frac{-B \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-x_g)(y_i-y_g)}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-x_g)(x_i-x_g)} $
$B = \frac{-A \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i-y_g)(x_i-x_g)}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i-y_g)(y_i-y_g)} $

Now if I plug one of these equations into the other the $A$ and $B$ cancel out, leaving me with identity without any $A$ nor $B$ to compute! Why is this the case?

One thing I would like to point out is that since the normal $(A, B)$ is (or just could be?) of unit length I know there is constraint: $A^2 + B^2 = 1$. If I use this condition along with one (the first one) of the two equations listed above I get perfectly valid result. The thing I don't really get is why do I need to make use of this constraint? I don't really care about the length of the $(A, B)$ normal. Or do I? Why would I need this sort of a "tie" between $A$ and $B$? I thought that unit length-ness is just an extra information I could use to simplify my calculations, but is not mandatory to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cost function is not perfect. The distance of the points to the line has to be normalized with the magnitude of the normal vector i.e, $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. After that your constraint makes sense.

Comment: Yes, exactly :). I forgot that the distance expressed by the general $Ax + By + C = 0$ formula must be normalized.

Comment: Also, I wondered why I had to use square of distance rather that just distance. The reason is that the "real" distance (non-signed) formula contains absolute value which is not differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

Sai Kashyap provided valid part of the answer. Here goes the second part.

Equating $A$ to $0$ (and making use of $A^2 + B^2 = 1$) does not guarantee finding minimum. It can also return maximum. That's why it is also necessary to equate $B$ to $0$ and find its corresponding $A$. Then we go through all of the $A$ and $B$ pairs to find which is minimum and which is maximum.